# What's the point of having both getdirents and getdirents64?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems

I'm examining all syscalls of linux kernel, I see two functions that will get the contents of a directory:

```
asmlinkage long sys_getdents(unsigned int fd,
                struct linux_dirent __user *dirent,
                unsigned int count);
asmlinkage long sys_getdents64(unsigned int fd,
                struct linux_dirent64 __user *dirent,
                unsigned int count);
```

So why should there be both `linux_dirent64` and `linux_dirent` structure? I mean, one structure should be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is not just because of the need for backward compatibility. There is one more reason to it. 
The Linux kernel supports the 32 bit processes running on the userland even though the Kernel is running on the 64 bit mode. This is called the 32 bit compatibility mode. So for the processes running in 32 bit mode, everything looks like a 32 bit system. They still would be calling the 32 bit old style syscalls etc. But in the kernel a 32bit equivalent of each 64 bit syscall is kept which eventually calls the 64 bit syscalls itself after doing required conversion to 64. This is called 64 bit compatibility mode and the syscalls are compat syscalls. The reason for all these circus is to enable the userspace process to run transparent of kernel mode. (No userspace process vendor like to port their software to 64 bit because of the whatever business priorities they may have)

Comment: yup. The variations support both executables compiled under the former regime, and new compilations of old code that declines to upgrade.

Comment: This is wrong, getdents and getdents64 are there for large file support, not for 32 bit compatibility mode: getdents64 exists on 32 bit platforms as well (and exists, in fact, solely for the benefit of 32 bit platforms as on 64 bit platforms getdents and getdents64 are identical).

Answer (score 2):

The 32-bit version supports code compiled back when 64 bits were just a myth, like flying cars or responsive politicians.

Answer (score 1):

Historically, file sizes, offsets, inode numbers and so on were "unsigned long" in the UNIX API, which has 32 bits on 32 bit platforms, and therefore are good for 2GB (when signed) filesizes. Enourmous back then, not even good enough for a DVD image or many movies nowadays.

To handle files large than that, most syscalls (and structures passed to/from them) dealing with this had to be changed, and often this version got a "64" suffix.

getdents is one of these - getdents uses a struct with "unsigned long" for the directory offset and inode numbers, while getdents64 uses s64 and u64 (64 bit types) for the same.

Similar syscalls are stat/stat64, statfs/statfs64, sendfile/sendfile64 and so on.

On 64 bit systems, some of the older ones of these syscalls do not exist, as they are often identical to the base version. Some have 64 bit counterparts, because even 64 bit systems might have backward compatibility issues (e.g. with 32bit inode numbers).